# cross account S3 bucket replication via replication rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two buckets:

- "source-bucket" (in AWS account 88888888).
- "destination-bucket" (in AWS account 99999999)

Both buckets have versioning enabled and are located in the same region (eu-west-1).

In the source bucket, I've created a Replication-rule with the following settings:

[image]

[image]

I opted for automatic role creation, which created a role with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectRetention",
                "s3:GetObjectLegalHold"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:ReplicateTags",
                "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

According to the documentation found here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-2.html
, I've added a bucket policy to "destination-bucket", which looks as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Set permissions for objects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::88888888:role/service-role/auto-created-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Set permissions on bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::88888888:role/service-role/auto-created-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

But, when I add a file to the source bucket, nothing seems happens.
Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

The AWS docs aren't the best here. From your pictures I see you have enabled the setting "change object ownership to destination bucket owner" (as most people would).
However, this requires an extra permission on the destination side give them ownership. `s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner`

The following policy should work for you

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Set permissions for objects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::88888888:role/service-role/auto-created-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Set permissions on bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::88888888:role/service-role/auto-created-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

To debug this issue I used `aws s3api head-object --bucket <bucket> --key <prefix> --query ReplicationStatus` to see the replication failed and then I added `s3:*` permission on the destination side to see if it was a permission issue. Which in this case it was.

Comment: You just save my half-day !!

Answer (score 1):

Check if this helps.

> By default, Amazon S3 doesn't replicate objects that are stored at rest using server-side encryption with AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) customer master keys (CMKs). To replicate encrypted objects, you modify the bucket replication configuration to tell Amazon S3 to replicate these objects.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-4.html

Comment: Thx, but encryption is disabled in my test setup.